# Appending an array in a singleton class and count returned 0 in another Controller

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, singleton

```
let newFeed = Feed(profilePicture: "image_boyce_avenue",artistName: "Boyce Avenue", videoUrl: "boyce_avenue-dont_let_me_down",videoTitle:"Dont let me down", videoViews: "160",likes: "200",shoutouts: "200",comments: [Comment.init(userName: "Megan Nicole", userComment: "Wow!", likes: "50", timeOfComment: Date())],votes: "50", dateCreated: Date(), feedType: FeedContentType.VIDEO_FEED.rawValue, userActivity :"This user liked your video")

    ArtistProfileData.sharedInstance.add(array: newFeed,artistName: name)
    print("Count in dictionary ",ArtistProfileData.sharedInstance.artistProfileDict[name]?.feeds.count as Any)
```

In the code above the array count is returned correct after appending.

When I try to access the same array in another class the count returned is 0.

```
print("Count in anotherbview",ArtistProfileData.sharedInstance.artistProfileDict[artistSelected]?.feeds.count as Any)

return (ArtistProfileData.sharedInstance.artistProfileDict[artistSelected]?.feeds.count)!
```

Following is the Singleton class

```
class ArtistProfileData{

static let sharedInstance = ArtistProfileData()

var artistProfileDict = [String : Profile]()
var loggedInUserProfile = Profile(artistName: "John Smith", artistDescription: "Admiral of New England, English soldier, explorer, and author.", totalLikes: "174", totalViews: "200", totalFollowing: "100",totalFollowers:"50",imageUrl:"image_singer", feeds:[])

private init() {
    getProfilesDictionary()
}

func getProfilesDictionary()->[String: Profile]{
    artistProfileDict["John Smith"] = loggedInUserProfile
    return artistProfileDict
}

func add(array: Feed, artistName: String) {
    ArtistProfileData.sharedInstance.artistProfileDict[artistName]!.feeds.append(array)
  }

}
```

Following is the profile object

```
struct Profile {
    var artistName: String
    var artistDescription: String
    var totalLikes: String
    var totalViews: String
    var totalFollowing: String
    var totalFollowers: String
    var imageUrl: String
    var feeds : [Feed]

    init(artistName: String,artistDescription:String,totalLikes:String,totalViews:String,totalFollowing:String,totalFollowers:String,imageUrl:String, feeds:[Feed]) {

        self.artistName = artistName
        self.artistDescription = artistDescription
        self.totalLikes = totalLikes
        self.totalViews = totalViews
        self.totalFollowing = totalFollowing
        self.totalFollowers = totalFollowers
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.feeds = feeds
    }
}
```

I cannot figure out the problem here. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How your `Profile` object looks like?

Comment: I have edited the question @ingaham

Comment: Unfortunately the bug is not related with this code probably... I just copied & treid your code (create the Feed struct too), and it works as expected. However your solution is make it really easy to modify the `feeds` array, so probably at some point you override it or remove the object from it

Answer (score 0):

Try by replacing this code :

```
func getProfilesDictionary()->[String: Profile]{
    artistProfileDict["John Smith"] = loggedInUserProfile
    return artistProfileDict
}
```

with this code :

```
func getProfilesDictionary()->[String: Profile]{
    ArtistProfileData.sharedInstance.artistProfileDict["John Smith"] = loggedInUserProfile
    return artistProfileDict
}
```

I have not tested it but it should work.

Comment: No it does not work. The view does not load at all when I change the code to this @Jagdeep Singh